# phonology transformational method

Tags: regex, nlp

I have a word list of a particular language in [IPA symbols](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet). I also have some rules in regular expressions to convert the input word list into a new word list of another language in IPA symbols. How can I convert that?

My regular expression rules are like this

```
y=> j / $_
```

which means *'y' is replaced by 'j' when it is in first place in a particular word*.

And the input word list contains some words ready to be converted to a new word list in IPA symbols.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting question, but it is difficult to answer without **1)** sample input strings and the results you expect for each and **2)** clarification what regex dialect you are using.

Comment: @J0e3gan : 1) Two sample input strings are -- yəmə   and mən̪uʂyə
                                   result I expect are -- jɑmɑ  and  mɑn̥usɑ respectively
                     2) I am yet to use regex dialect

Comment: What about 2) the regex dialect you are using?  In other words, in what programming language are you trying to do this with regex?

Comment: 2) I am yet to use regex dialect

Comment: Also, what are the mappings for other characters (e.g. like y => j but for a, m etetcetera)?

Comment: Okay, so you are trying to understand the efficacy of doing using a regex and will then proceed with a regex solution in a language to be determined?

Comment: y=> j is a rule...by looking at the input and output symbol we have to create such rules, eg ə=> ɑ is another rule..

Comment: Yes Sir, I am trying to understand the efficacy of doing using a regex first.

Comment: The key to answering this is then a full description of the transformational rules.  Without that it will be impossible to provide a useful answer.  I searched the web on "phonology transformational method" but did not find anything that seemed clearly related to your question: shed further light on the transformational rules.

Comment: I have given the two examples of two words...to transform the input we have mapped the characters(rules)...example of two rules given also above...so after this, I am trying how the two rules can be implemented so that we can get desired output by inserting the input words.